# SQL query building practices

Tags: php, sql

I am building a SQL query that dynamically changes based on passed in `$_GET` parameters.  I simply want to know if putting in a 'dummy' constraint is an 'acceptable' practice, so I do not have to check the SQL string for the existence of 'where' before I add new constraints (each time).

For example, the 'dummy' constraint':

`$sql = "select * from users u where u.id != 0";`

Now, in each block where I determine if I have to add more constraints, I can just do:

```
if (!empty($uid))
    $sql .= " and (u.id = {$uid})";
```

Instead of doing:

```
if (!empty($uid)) {
    $sql .= strpos($sql, "where") === false ? " where " : " and ";
    $sql .= " (u.id = {$uid})";
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just write a method called, say, `addClause`?

Comment: Yes... I understand your comment - that's what I would ultimately do as to not have tons of repeat code.  However, there would still be just as many checks for the existence of 'where' each time the method is called.

Comment: This code seems to be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. As for the question, you really should abstract it all away in a `QueryBuilder` object.

Comment: Don't worry - the actual code is run through PDO's prepare / execute methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used that convention (although I usually use `WHERE 1=1 AND`.) Depending on your RDBMS, using a column there could affect performance. For example, if you had an index that would otherwise be a covering index except for that column.

Please make sure that you understand the potential pitfalls of this kind of dynamic SQL, but if it's what you ultimately end up doing, adding that extra bit seems to make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending to the SQL string for each check, you could collect the conditions:

```
if ($_GET["uid"]) {
      $where[] = array("u.id =", $_GET->sql["uid"]);

if ($_GET["photo"]) {
      $where[] = array("u.has_photo =", 1);
```

And complete the SQL string when you're through:

```
foreach ($where as $add) {
    $sql .= ...;
}
```

Otherwise, it's an acceptable approach. I wouldn't turn out the big weapons and use a full blown ORM query builder for that.

Answer (score 0):

from the manual

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1
```

so yes, you can do that